# "Role model" Vs "Exemplar"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

- > [Role model:](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/role-model) 
  >   Someone whose behaviour, attitudes etc people try to copy because they admire them.
- > [Exemplar:](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/exemplar) 
  >   An exemplar is someone or something that is considered to be so good that they should be copied or imitated.

### **My question:**

I was wondering how these two differ in meaning and can change the meaning of a sentence?

**Example:**

- > I have always wanted to be a positive and good  ___________ for my brother.

a. role model 
b. exemplar

Based on dictionary definitions I think they both mean the same and work interchangeably in this example.

Please kindly enlighten me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/exemplar), exemplar can only be applied to a thing, not a person. Merriam-Webster is not clear whether it can be applied to a person, but Collins and [Oxford Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/exemplar?q=exemplar) state that it can be. I personally have never heard of it used about a person, although if you google it you can find a few written references- mainly in religious texts.

As the Cambridge Dictionary states, exemplar is a formal word: I think you would be much better off using role model.

Note that the definition of role model does not state whether the behaviour of the role model is good or bad- only that somebody else admires them. Somebody could have a mass murderer as a role model, and go on to become a mass murderer themselves.

Conversely, exemplar is always good, so you don't need to include the words **positive and good** in your sentence:

> I have always wanted to be an exemplar for my brother.

Comment: Let's check if my take has been correct or not @JavaLatte. As you said, I can say: "I have always wanted to be **an exemplar** for my brother.", but is it the same as "I have always wanted to be **a positive and good role model** for my brother."? Please explain that to me.

Comment: @A-friend, yes, it is the same.